# Syntax for NSFetchedResulstsSectionInfo objectAtIndex - Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, subscript

I'm looking to conform the following objective-c syntax in swift. I have looked at other examples and believe I need to use the **"subscript syntax"**

I've had success with other statements, however i have drawn a blank on the one below:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger rows = 0;
    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count] > 0) {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        rows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: check this http://rshankar.com/coredata-tutoiral-in-swift-using-nsfetchedresultcontroller/

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer thanks to Kalpesh on http://rshankar.com/coredata-tutoiral-in-swift-using-nsfetchedresultcontroller/

```
return self.fetchedResultsController.sections[section].numberOfObjects
```